# How do I specify a default parameter value for a Pylons action?

Tags: routes, pylons

I have an action which looks like this:

```
class ArticleController(BaseController):
    def all(self, page, pagesize):
```

I want to be able to access `/article/all/{page}/{pagesize}`, with default values for `page` and `pagesize`.

I tried setting the default values in the action method, but then apparently both `page` and `pagesize` get set to the default value if I only set a `page` value.

I also tried something like this, but it doesn't work either:

```
map.connect('/article/all/{page}/{pagesize}', controller='article',
            action='all')
map.connect('/', controller='article', action='all', page=0, pagesize=5)
map.connect('/article/all/', controller='article', action='all', page=0,
            pagesize=5)
```

Actually, in that case it works when I access `/` or `/article/all/`.
But it doesn't work with `/article/all` (even when I remove the trailing `/` in the route accordingly).

Looking at Routes' documentation it looks like default values shouldn't work at all in that case, so maybe it's some kind or undefined behavior.

Anyway, my question is, how can I get `all()` to be called with default values for `page` and `pagesize` when accessing `/article/all` and `/article/all/42`?

(I know I could use the query string instead. `map.redirect()` also kind of does the trick, but I don't really want to redirect.)

Answer (score 2):

Your routes should look like that:

```
map.connect('/article/all',
    controller='Article', action='all',
    page=0, pagesize=5)
map.connect('/article/all/{page}',
    controller='Article', action='all',
    pagesize=5)
map.connect('/article/all/{page}/{pagesize}',
    controller='Article', action='all')
```

You don't have to put default values in the method itself. So your controller should look like this:

```
class ArticleController(BaseController):
    def all(self, page, pagesize):
        return 'Page: %s. Pagesize: %s.' % (page, pagesize)
```

Comment: Apparently, having several URLs for the same resource is considered as a bad practice (http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/urls-routing-and-dispatch.html#route-minimization). So I guess I'll stick to `redirect()`.

Comment: Weird it doesn't work for you. It works perfeclty here with a fresh new Pylons 1.0 projet. Also I guess you're right with the redirection.